# Not able to make a User with the same username that I deleted

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-8

**Laravel + MongoDB**

This is my `Store()` method in `UserController`:

```
       public function store()
        {
            $userData = request()->get('user', []);
            .
            . 
            //Checking if credentials satisfied
            .
            .
    
            try
            {
                $user = User::create($userData);
            }
            catch(BulkWriteException $ex)
            {
                abort(409, trans('errors.EXISTS_USERNAME'));
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                abort(409, trans('errors.EXISTS_USERNAME'));
            }
            return [
                'status' => 'success',
                'result' => $user,
            ];
        }
```

Close up to the Create() method in the above Code:

```
    public static function create($parameters)
    {
        return static::query()->create($parameters);
    }
```

Close up to the Create() method in the above Code:

```
  public function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
            $instance->save();
        });
    }
```

So the problem is When I delete a `User` for example with `username: "X"` I can't make a new `User` with `username: "X"` and it gives the error u see in the exception.

The deletion method is soft-delete which means the user not completely deleted from DB it just gives the user `deleted_at` property so laravel will understand that act to this user like a deleted user which means when I use a query like `User::where('username',"X")->get()` it won't show me any result which means the data is deleted.

so here's the deal, I can't understand why it throws me exception about `Existing Username` while laravel can't see the user as a data.

What I want to do is fixing this issue without using force-delete and with only using soft-delete

Comment: this code shows nothing, give a reproducible example

Comment: @FlashThunder wdym "shows nothing" ? this is where the problem is , and I explained the whole situation . Actually can't paste the whole project here.

Comment: where is the user creation? where is the user deletion? how do you actually delete the user? how do you actually create the user? what is the structure of db? loooots of informations are missing

Comment: I am not trying to be mean, just no one will answer this question with these information missing. How can we answer the question when we don't know how is it actually implemented?

Comment: @FlashThunder you completely misunderstood my question I will update the code for you

Comment: I'm not sure if I did, just ... maybe you are soft-deleting it or not clearing the cache. Hard to tell, as you didn't give enough of information.

Comment: Maybe you use soft deletes and unique index on username?

Comment: Database dont know about soft deletes. When you set deleted_at - row with username mot deleted, jusr updated from database vision

Comment: How does the database know about soft deletes? I would assume that the exception (which you haven't shared any details about) contains some information that helps you resolve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You note that your username is a unique field.

You are using Laravel soft-deletes.

This means that Laravel keeps the record in the database, and places a non-null value inside `deleted_at` within your users table.

Because the data *is not deleted* from the database, the database cannot create a new record with the same name "X", because that record "X" already exists -- it just appears deleted to Laravel due to the soft delete.

If you *want* the protection of a unique user name, this is not a problem: it is working correctly by preventing you from duplicating a `username` against ALL users ever, even those you have had to delete.  You may need to keep the user data over time (thus the soft-delete), and this would successfully prevent you from duplicating even an old 'removed' user.  If you don't want this protection, remove the unique field from the `username`.

Answer (score -1):

You can take the following actions to enable signup using the same email once a user's account is deleted:

1. Generate Observer: php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User

class UserObserver
{
/**
* Handle the User "deleted" event.
*
* @param  \App\Models\User  $user
* @return void
*/
public function deleted(User $user)
{
$user->update([
'email' => time() . '::' . $user->email
]);
}
}

3. Register Observer: Register the observer in the AppServiceProvider boot method or in the EventServiceProvider:

`

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{
User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
}
`

Comment: Please share more details. What does your code really do? To me, it looks like you're randomly changing the mail address of an existing account

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).